# Graphiz: direction nodes as an L

Tags: graphviz, dot

i want the main nodes looking like a L

[image]

Here is my sample graph,

https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20rankdir%20%3D%20TD%3B%0A%0A%20%20A1%20-%3E%20B1%20-%3E%20C1%20-%3E%20C2%0A%20%20%0A%20%20subgraph%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20rank%20%3D%20sink%20%3B%20rankdir%20%3D%20TB%20%3B%20A1%3B%20B1%3B%20C1%3B%20%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20subgraph%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20rank%20%3D%20same%20%3B%20rankdir%20%3D%20LR%20%3B%20C1%3B%20C2%3B%20%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%0A%20%20%0A%20%20A1_x1%20-%3E%20A1%0A%20%20A1_x2%20-%3E%20A1%0A%20%20A1_x3%20-%3E%20A1%0A%20%20A1_x4%20-%3E%20A1%0A%20%20A1_x99%20-%3E%20A1%0A%0A%20%20B1_x1%20-%3E%20B1%0A%20%20B1_x2%20-%3E%20B1%0A%20%20B1_x3%20-%3E%20B1%0A%20%20B1_x4%20-%3E%20B1%0A%20%20B1_x99%20-%3E%20B1%0A%0A%20%20C1_x1%20-%3E%20C1%0A%20%20C1_x2%20-%3E%20C1%0A%20%20C1_x3%20-%3E%20C1%0A%20%20C1_x4%20-%3E%20C1%0A%20%20C1_x99%20-%3E%20C1%0A%20%20%0A%20%20C2_x1%20-%3E%20C2%0A%20%20C2_x2%20-%3E%20C2%0A%20%20C2_x3%20-%3E%20C2%0A%20%20C2_x4%20-%3E%20C2%0A%20%20C2_x99%20-%3E%20C2%0A%7D

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**rankdir** applies to the entire graph

You did not specify how you wanted the other nodes placed, so I guessed:

```
digraph G {
  graph [ splines=false]
  { node[group=G] A1 B1  C1 }       // group helps vert alignment
  { rank = same  C1 C2  } 
  { edge[minlen=3] A1 -> B1 -> C1}  // minlen spreads vertically
  C1 -> C2      
  
  A1_x1 -> A1
  A1_x2 -> A1
  A1_x3 -> A1
  A1_x4 -> A1
  A1_x99 -> A1

  B1_x1 -> B1
  B1_x2 -> B1
  B1_x3 -> B1
  B1_x4 -> B1
  B1_x99 -> B1

  C1_x1 -> C1
  C1_x2 -> C1
  C1_x3 -> C1
  C1_x4 -> C1
  C1_x99 -> C1
  
  C2_x1 -> C2
  C2_x2 -> C2
  C2_x3 -> C2
  C2_x4 -> C2
  C2_x99 -> C2
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Great, the other nodes are very mutch (>400) and should be placed some how. Might you please explain what you habe done?

Comment: Do you understand the comments in my code?